# Sudden FPS drop in Cemu BOTW caused by unknown monster only

Tags: pc, zelda-breath-of-the-wild, emulation, performance, cemu-emulator

Using latest **Cemu 1.26.2f** with AMD Radeon HD 7800, I get a solid **27-30 FPS** with the default settings. But whenever Link is facing in the direction of this monster (looking south from Riverside Stable on Hyrule Field), there is a sudden drop to an unbearable **5-10 FPS**, which lasts until the camera is moved away from it.

Also, the monster seems *bugged* somehow, because it barely moves in a sluggish back-and-forth, senseless fashion. I'm attaching the **Graphic Packs** settings as well. Those OpenGL GPU workarounds don't have any effect. Forcing **Vertical Sync** and enabling **Triple buffering** as all youtubers suggest doesn't help either. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated and properly upvoted, thanks. If you know the **monster's name**, please let me know so I can perform a more specific search for this issue.

*Ps. please avoid suggesting to buy an RTX 3080 card to deal with this glitch; I know my Radeon is quite old but it works perfectly fine except for that little guy in the screenshot.*

[image: BOTW FPS drop Hyrule Field]

[image: CEMU Graphic Packs]

[image: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Global Settings]

This is the HW monitor when this monster appears:

[image: Open Hardware Monitor]

Comment: That's [Farosh](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Farosh), the electric dragon spirit.

Comment: I solved this problem by changing from OpenGL to Vulkan. It turns out Vulkan mode is not provided by the driver to Windows 8.1, only Windows 10, which I have installed now with great success.

Comment: Great! And since you solved your own problem, consider posting an answer and accept it :)

Comment: That GPU is older than the Wii U itself. Don't expect to ever get good performance on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to switch to **Vulkan** API instead of **OpenGL**. The drivers for Windows 8.1 do not provide Vulkan support so I had to migrate to Windows 10, which I used to avoid like the plague due to its errors. Everything runs smooth and much faster than with OpenGL now.